# Cannot access this.setState or this.state inside Ant Modal confirm ok/cancel function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, react-class-based-component

I'm having issues with accessing `this.state` and `this.setState` inside the onCancel/onOk function. I want to modify the state after confirmation or canceling the pop-up modal. If anyone's got a different approach, your guidance would be helpful.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'antd';

class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      bankInfo: 100,
    };
  }

  onButtonClicked() {
    this.setState({ bankInfo: 200 });            // works fine
    Modal.confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure delete this item?',
      okType: 'danger',
      onOk() {
        this.setState({ bankInfo: 300 }); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
      },
      onCancel() {
        this.setState({ bankInfo: 400 }); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onButtonClicked.bind(this)}>Click Me</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExampleClass;
```

Comment: you need to `bind` those before passing them off to `Modal.confirm`.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a simple code snippet for the above missing binding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer to use arrow function

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'antd';

class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      bankInfo: 100,
    };
  }

  onButtonClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ bankInfo: 200 });
    Modal.confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure delete this item?',
      okType: 'danger',
      onOk: () => {
        this.setState({ bankInfo: 300 });
      },
      onCancel: () => {
        this.setState({ bankInfo: 400 });
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onButtonClicked}>Click Me</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExampleClass;
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for.

Comment: For the curious: [this is why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) the arrow function works where the non-arrow function doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your method to the class.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'antd';

class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      bankInfo: 100,
    };
  }
  onOkHandler = () => {this.setState({ bankInfo: 300 })}
  onCancelHandler = () => {this.setState({ bankInfo: 400 })}
  onButtonClicked() {
    this.setState({ bankInfo: 200 });            // works fine
    Modal.confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure delete this item?',
      okType: 'danger',
      onOk() {
        this.onOkHandler()
      },
      onCancel() {
       this.onCancelHandler()
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onButtonClicked.bind(this)}>Click Me</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExampleClass;
```

Comment: It works but I was able to achieve my goal by using the arrow function. Thank you so much for the support :)

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely cleaner. I post my preferred coding style :)

Comment: Anyway, happy to help!

Comment: Actually I needed to use some params which were provided to onButtonClicked() method and use them inside the setState function. So using arrow function was the option for that.

Comment: good, imho it will be a good idea to add a short summary of your final solution and the resining, for future devs :)